# Unable to get property 'queryselectorall' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I am getting below mentioned error in my jQuery function:

```
var timer = document.getElementById(id);
var pdays = timer.querySelector('.days');
var phours = timer.querySelector('.hours');
var pminutes = timer.querySelector('.minutes');
var pseconds = timer.querySelector('.seconds');
```

> **0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'querySelector' of undefined or null reference**

Please suggest to me where I can find **jQuery file** for `.queryselectorall()` method or remove above mentioned error in jQuery code ?

Comment: That means `timer` doesn't exist, are you waiting until document is ready and are you sure the element exists?

Comment: i just want to know where i can find file for .querySelector method above example only for reference

Comment: @DavidR : Have you read error seriously...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a suggestion!
maybe your JavaScript is executing before your page loads so your `document.querySelectorAll()` code is returning data with undefined or null reference (zero length).

try to wrap with onload()

```
onload = yourFunction(){
document.querySelectorAll()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion :-)